# How to select the records without duplicating form inner join tables

Tags: sql-server

From this query how can I get the records without duplicate value.
I need to get the values, if the name from the table a and account from the table c should view when the dates field is maximum.

```
SELECT
      a.name
    , a.dates
    , b.da
    , a.id
    , b.client
    , b.[Address]
    , b.[City]
    , b.[State]
    , b.dot
    , b.Score
    , b.Pay
    , b.code
    , b.[Country]
FROM a
INNER JOIN c ON a.Account = c.Account
INNER JOIN b ON [a].name = b.name
WHERE c.users = 00
    AND b.Act = 1
ORDER BY a.dates
```

Comment: Mysql or SQL-Server, that are very different RDBMS

Comment: How your table structure Looks like

Comment: You should provide more info on duplicates you are getting ad what have you tried so far

Comment: Please provide actual and expected result...

Answer (score 0):

Use `DISTINCT` ?

```
SELECT DISTINCT
      a.name
    , a.dates
    , b.da
    , a.id
    , b.client
    , b.[Address]
    , b.[City]
    , b.[State]
    , b.dot
    , b.Score
    , b.Pay
    , b.code
    , b.[Country]
FROM a
INNER JOIN c ON a.Account = c.Account
INNER JOIN b ON [a].name = b.name
WHERE c.users = 00
    AND b.Act = 1
ORDER BY a.dates
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using CTE ?

```
with CTE_duplicate 
as
(SELECT 
  a.name
, a.dates
, b.da
, a.id
, b.client
, b.[Address]
, b.[City]
, b.[State]
, b.dot
, b.Score
, b.Pay
, b.code
, b.[Country]
, row_number() over ( partition by a.name
, a.dates
, b.da
, a.id
, b.client
, b.[Address]
, b.[City]
, b.[State]
, b.dot
, b.Score
, b.Pay
, b.code
, b.[Country]   order by a.name
, a.dates
, b.da
, a.id
, b.client
, b.[Address]
, b.[City]
, b.[State]
, b.dot
, b.Score
, b.Pay
, b.code
, b.[Country] ) as rownumber
FROM a
INNER JOIN c ON a.Account = c.Account
INNER JOIN b ON [a].name = b.name
WHERE c.users = 00
AND b.Act = 1
) select * from  CTE_duplicate where rownumber=1 order by dates;
```